# Reanimating a view when using layoutanimation

Tags: android, animation

Using a layoutanimation on one of  my views.

```
android:layoutAnimation="@anim/animate_layout"
```

The animation is done each time one enters that view. It will however not run if that view was already active and the user changed to another application and then returned to it. In order to do that, I need to overwrite the `onresume()` method and call it from there.

How can I call the layoutAnimation from within the code in order to run it again for the whole layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, besides what Pentium10 suggested, would be trying to do this:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(ctx, android.R.anim.fade_out);
target.startAnimation(animation);
```

Where `ctx` could be something like `YourActivity.this`, and target is the `View` you want to animate.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [LayoutAnimationController](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html) and start()

Comment: Tried it by both using the constructor and even setanimation before calling its start method. It still didnt work. Should there have been more steps than adding the animation object and calling it's start method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also trying to get my animation to start over when the user gets to se the layout again. I get force close with this code implemented.

```
public void onResume(){
     super.onResume();
     View layout = findViewById(R.layout.main);
     Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(CrookTranslate.this, R.anim.fade_from_left);
     layout.startAnimation(animation);        
    }   

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layoutAnimation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:animation="@anim/from_left"
android:id="@+id/fade_from_left"
android:delay="3.0"
/>
```

`enter code here`